# UINavigationController madness?

Tags: ios

I have two issues that I don't understand and am hoping that someone can help.

This code doesn't work for taking my existing UINavigationController hierarchy from a split view controller and taking over the screen with it. I just get a dark screen

```
UINavigationController* myself = self.navigationController;
[myself removeFromParentViewController];

UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionnaireViewController"];
[myself pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.window.rootViewController = myself;
```

However, this code does work. Why can I set the rootViewController to a new UINavigationController but not self.navigationController?

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* myself = self.navigationController;
[myself removeFromParentViewController];
navController.viewControllers = myself.viewControllers;

UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionnaireViewController"];
[navController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

My second issue is in restoring the navigation controller to the splitViewController when the user goes "back". I know from experience that I can assign a new UINavigationController to the detailView, but I cannot assign self.navigationController.

I think the issues are the same issue. For some reason a new UINavigationController is not the same as a UIView's navigationController. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Meddling with `UIWindow` is not very safe.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, I can think of 2 rather simple options

a) iOS 5.1+ has an option to show/hide the `RootViewController` of your split and show with a swipe gesture, and work with that

b) Create your own `UIViewController` that emulates `UISplitViewController`, and hide the left part whenever you need to

Comment: I decided to use a modalViewController instead. I can embed that in a NavigationController if I want and easily dismiss it to return to the previous splitViewController.